# How to upload my video using Video module and CKEditor?

Tags: 7, wysiwyg, files

I'm trying to upload my custom videos to my Drupal 7.28 site. I want to add videos in my most of the posts or pages.

I've installed the [Video](https://www.drupal.org/project/video) module and also have `CKEditor` module working. Is there any way I can upload the video directly inside `CKEditor`?

How can i do this?
Is there any module that simplifies this?

Comment: Have you tried the [Media](https://drupal.org/project/media) module? I wouldn't exactly call it *simple* but I think you're more likely to find support on that here.